# postgresql json to columns error Character with value must be escaped

Tags: json, postgresql, insert, special-characters

I try to load some data from a table containing json rows.
There is one field that can contain special chars as \t and \r, and I want to keep them as is in the new table.

Here is my file:

```
{"text_sample": "this is a\tsimple test", "number_sample": 4}
```

Here is what I do:

```
Drop table if exists temp_json;
Drop table if exists test;
create temporary table temp_json (values text);

copy temp_json from '/path/to/file';

create table test as (select 
        (values->>'text_sample') as text_sample,
        (values->>'number_sample') as number_sample
        from   (
           select replace(values,'\','\\')::json as values
           from   temp_json
       ) a);
```

I keep getting this error:

```
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type json
DETAIL:  Character with value 0x09 must be escaped.
CONTEXT:  JSON data, line 1: ...g] Objection to PDDRP Mediation (was Re: Call for...
```

How do I need to escape those characters?
Thanks a lot

Comment: Post sample data containing the offending rows.

Comment: I updated with all the needed details

Comment: `copy temp_json from program 'sed -e ''s/\\/\\\\/g'' /path/to/file';`?

Answer (score 5):

As mentioned in [Andrew Dunstan's PostgreSQL and Technical blog](http://adpgtech.blogspot.com/2014/09/importing-json-data.html?m=1)

> In text mode, COPY will be simply defeated by the presence of a backslash in the JSON. So, for example, any field that contains an embedded double quote mark, or an embedded newline, or anything else that needs escaping according to the JSON spec, will cause failure. And in text mode you have very little control over how it works - you can't, for example, specify a different ESCAPE character. So text mode simply won't work.

so we have to turn around to the `CSV` format mode.

```sql
copy the_table(jsonfield) 
from '/path/to/jsondata' 
csv quote e'\x01' delimiter e'\x02';
```

In the official document [sql-copy](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/sql-copy.html), some Parameters list here:

```sql
COPY table_name [ ( column_name [, ...] ) ]
    FROM { 'filename' | PROGRAM 'command' | STDIN }
    [ [ WITH ] ( option [, ...] ) ]
    [ WHERE condition ]

where option can be one of:

    FORMAT format_name
    FREEZE [ boolean ]
    DELIMITER 'delimiter_character'
    NULL 'null_string'
    HEADER [ boolean ]
    QUOTE 'quote_character'
    ESCAPE 'escape_character'
    FORCE_QUOTE { ( column_name [, ...] ) | * }
    FORCE_NOT_NULL ( column_name [, ...] )
    FORCE_NULL ( column_name [, ...] )
    ENCODING 'encoding_name'
```

- FORMAT

  - Selects the data format to be read or written: text, csv (Comma Separated Values), or binary. The default is text.
- QUOTE

  - Specifies the quoting character to be used when a data value is quoted. The default is double-quote. This must be a single one-byte character. This option is allowed only when using CSV format.
- DELIMITER

  - Specifies the character that separates columns within each row (line) of the file. The default is a tab character in text format, a comma in CSV format. This must be a single one-byte character. This option is not allowed when using binary format.
- NULL

  - Specifies the string that represents a null value. The default is \N (backslash-N) in text format, and an unquoted empty string in CSV format. You might prefer an empty string even in text format for cases where you don't want to distinguish nulls from empty strings. This option is not allowed when using binary format.
- HEADER

  - Specifies that the file contains a header line with the names of each column in the file. On output, the first line contains the column names from the table, and on input, the first line is ignored. This option is allowed only when using CSV format.

Comment: Hi, I am very new to this field. what are "e'\x01'" and  "e'\x02'" referring to?

Comment: The strings `\x01` and `\x02` are examples of byte literals in Python. They represent the characters with the ASCII values 1 and 2, respectively. These characters are non-printable and are often used for control purposes in various protocols... I use them because we don't use them in nomal situation. You can chose other charcaters you like instead.

Answer (score 3):

Copy the file as `csv` with a different quoting character and delimiter:

```
drop table if exists test;
create table test (values jsonb);
\copy test from '/path/to/file.csv' with (format csv, quote '|', delimiter ';');

select values ->> 'text_sample', values ->> 'number_sample'
from test;
          ?column?           | ?column? 
-----------------------------+----------
 this is a       simple test | 4
```

Comment: This isn't a solution it's a workaround for the specific case and data set.  What if the data contains the values you've suggested using for `quote` and `delimiter`?

Answer (score 0):

cast json as text, instead of getting text value from json. Eg:

```
t=# with j as (
        select '{"text_sample": "this is a\tsimple test", "number_sample": 4}'::json v
)
select v->>'text_sample' your, (v->'text_sample')::text better
from j;
            your             |          better
-----------------------------+--------------------------
 this is a       simple test | "this is a\tsimple test"
(1 row)
```

and to avoid 0x09 error, try using

```
replace(values,chr(9),'\t')
```

as in your example you replace backslash+t, not the actual `chr(9)`...

Comment: I get the same error when I try to do it on the whole table `with j as (
        select values::json v from temp_json
  )
select v->>'text_sample' your, (v->'text_sample')::text better
from j;
`

Comment: try regexp_replace(values, '\t', '\\t', 'g') ?.. your sample did not provoke the error, so I'm not sure what the problem - you probably have chr(9) as is in values, not the `\t`?..

Comment: I don' t want to escape the tab explicitly as it is possible to have any other kind of special chars, I'm looking instead for a generic way to do that

Comment: I think you will have to list them then. I dont know the general mask for "symbolless" characters , like 2,3,4,9,10,13 of ASCII